# Does PHP shell_exec add parentheses to the command?

Tags: php, bash, sh

I'm trying to run a cat command using the shell_exec function, to be more precise something like this:

```
cat <(echo "foo") bar.xml > foo-bar.xml
```

But I'm getting a syntax error like the following one:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm completely lost since this works fine locally and when the command is executed manually in the server, but when running the php script it returns the syntax error. Any clues?

Original code being used:

```
$shell_cmd = "cat <(echo \"{$this->xmlHeader}\") ";
$shell_cmd .= '\'' . $path . $filename . '\'' . " ";
$shell_cmd .= " > " . '\'' . $path . "hfb/" . strtolower(str_replace($this->replace_values, '', $hfbName)) . ".xml" . '\'';
shell_exec($shell_cmd);
```

Comment: Please show your code using shell_exec(). Did you read the manual using [escapeshellcmd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)?

Comment: I read it and used it but the output of it and my original string are identical so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Maybe you need to prefix a `$` before the parenthesis. sh !== bash

Comment: I added the code I'm using to generate the string and run it. It runs without problem locally on PHP 7.4, server is using 7.0 if that helps

Comment: You're completely and utterly right, the server for some absolutely stupid reason has 3 different shells installed. Thank you very much for your guidance!

Comment: `cat <(somecommand)` is basically useless -- the `cat` and the `<( )` effectively cancel each other out. Just use `somecommand` directly. BTW, that error message matches what the dash shell prints when it sees `<( )` in a command, so I suspect you're on a system where /bin/sh is dash (it'd also fail with bash in sh compatibility mode, but it'd give a slightly different error message).

Comment: @MASACR99 There's nothing stupid about it at all; it's really important that system scripts behave the same way regardless of what the user installs or configures, and `/bin/sh` pointing at a standards-only shell guarantees that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I didn't see the point of the `cat` either at first, but if you look closely it's being used to combine a literal string (from `echo`) with the content of a file. There's certainly other ways to achieve it, but it is doing *something*.

Comment: As usual, your question needs a [mcve]. Also, you have clearly shown that you didn't read the descriptions of the tags that you applied, which is bad, too.

Comment: @IMSoP Ah, I missed that. Good suggestions for alternates in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is likely to be which shell is used. It's not really documented, but I believe `shell_exec` will use `/bin/sh`, which will often be a minimal Posix-compliant shell (or a more complex shell emulating that compliance). That's very useful, because it means system scripts will always work the same way, regardless of what other shells are installed or configured for particular users.

When you log in directly, however, you're probably using bash, which has extra features such as the `<(...)` syntax for getting a named file descriptor from a command.

The best approach in this case is to make your command use only standardised facilities, which will be available in `/bin/sh`.

In particular, you are using `cat` to glue together a literal string from `echo` and a file:

```bash
cat <(echo "foo") bar.xml
```

That can be expressed instead by first echoing the string, and then outputting the file:

```bash
echo "foo"; cat bar.xml
```

To gather both into one output, place them in braces:

```bash
{ echo "foo"; cat bar.xml; } > foo-bar.xml
```

Alternatively, you can give `cat` an argument of `-` to concatenate standard input with one or more other files, so you could pipe the value from echo into it:

```bash
echo "foo" | cat - bar.xml > foo-bar.xml
```

Comment: That's correct, the server's sh is different than my local (which shouldn't be, but that's another thing). Thank you!