# Syntax error near unexpected token `(' when running shell script from XAMPP

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix, xampp

I'm trying to send a shell command directly from an index.php using the exec function as follows:

```
exec('shopt -s extglob && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/testes/xml/ && rm !(*.xml)');
```

However xampp returns an error in the log:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 1: `rm !(*.xml)'
```

I already gave permission for xampp to send commands via exec to the machine. Other commands like just removing files without the `!()` criteria works fine.

When I write `rm !(*.xml)` directly through the linux terminal works normally.

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate, but check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599583/does-php-shell-exec-add-parentheses-to-the-command to see if that helps explain it

Comment: Right, i understood. Then I need to use another command without `()`? Which command is equivalent to `rm !(*.xml)`?

Comment: What's the point in doing a `cd` in one shell, and the `rm` in a completely unrelated shell?

Comment: The `rm` works in the terminal, because you have turned _extglob_ on in the same shell where you run the command. In your PHP program, you turn it on in a different shell.

Comment: @user1934428 i already tried do it in a same shell in begin, but get the same problem, the code above it's like this cause it was my last try.

Comment: Well, clearly you can not seriously expect settings in one shell miraculously take effect in a different shell. So I suggest you post your attempts to do everything in the same shell, and then we can think why that failed.

Comment: @user1934428 

`exec('shopt -s extglob && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/testes/xml/ && rm !(*.xml)');`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code of the new attempt or other clarification instead of using comments for this purpose.

Comment: You are using the wrong shell. You have to execute your code with `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is **`sh:`**...

`shopt -s extglob` and extended globbing are `bash` extensions.

The `exec` function seems to use a POSIX shell, not `bash`, so you cannot directly use `bash` specific code.

Try something like

```
exec('bash -c "shopt -s extglob && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/testes/xml/ && rm !(*.xml)"');
```

or maybe even better put your code into a `bash` script file with interpreter specification

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and use

```
exec('/path/to/your_script');
```